# Rational as series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, rational-numbers, geometric-series

I was checking out a few things in the geometric series and apparently all rational numbers can be shown as a geometric series
$$
\frac{p}{q} = \frac{p}{{q + 1}} + \frac{p}{{(q + 1)^2 }} + \frac{p}{{(q + 1)^3 }} +  \ldots \,.
$$
What is a good proof for the equation?

Comment: Any number $N$, rational or irrational, can be expressed as the sum of a convergent geometric series: $$N=\frac N2+\frac N4+\frac N8+\cdots$$

Comment: Follow-up to bof's comment. All you need is the existence of a series $\sum a_n$ that converges to some number $a$. Then, given a number $N$, you can make a new series $\sum b_n$ with $b_n = N a_n / a$ so that $\sum b_n = \sum N a_n / a = N / a \sum a_n = N$. In their comment above, bof used the series defined by $a_n = 2^{-n}$ which converges to $a = 1$.

Comment: When proving a repeating decimal must be a rational number, we will use geometric series.

Answer (score 3):

You have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(q+1)^n} = \frac{1}{q+1} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{q+1}}= \frac{1}{q}
$$
using the formula for [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) applied to $r = \frac{1}{q+1}$, recalling that $0< \frac{1}{q+1} < 1$.
Therefore, 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p}{(q+1)^n}= \frac{p}{q}
$$
as claimed.

*I don't know who showed this first, but this is pretty straightforward.*

Answer (score 1):

The formula you wrote is not entirely correct. What you have is 
$$\tag1
\frac pq=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac p{p+q}\right)^k.
$$
This works nicely when $p,q>0$, since in this case $\left|\tfrac p{p+q}\right|<1$. The formula does not work for many negative numbers.

As for who may have come up with such formula, the geometric series has been known for millennia: the formula, at least for a finite sum, already appears in Euclid's work. This is basic enough that I doubt it ever appeared as a theorem in anybody's work.